# R - Collapsing rows of a dataframe with calculations on a column

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks something like this

```
sampleDF <- data.frame(entrezgene_id = c(rep(1, 20), rep(10, 25), rep(100, 5)),
                       ensembl_gene_id = c(rep("a", 7), rep("b", 8), rep("c", 7),
                                           rep("d", 8), rep("e", 15),
                                           rep("f", 2), rep("g", 2), rep("h", 1)),
                       transcript_length = sample(500:10000, 50))
```

I'd like to be able to collapse it into something like this

```
entrezgene_id   ensembl_gene_id medianTranscriptLength
            1                 a                   5795
            1                 b                   4981
            1                 c                   6526
           10                 c                   2307
           10                 d                   5044
           10                 e                   6069
          100                 f                   8669
          100                 g                 6570.5
          100                 h                   6997
```

where it iterates through each item in the first column, and for each item in the second column, calculates the median of the corresponding values in the third column.
The way I've done it now is to create another dataframe where the second column is the key. But then because of duplicates in the second column overlapping with with multiple entries of the first column (e.g. see ensembl_gene_id "c" in my example), I then had to create *another* dataframe where I flattened the entrezgene_id column. I'm sure there must be a shorter way of doing this. It seems simple enough, but I'm not sure how to do it. I'd really appreciate some help.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could use `aggregate` from `base R`

```
aggregate(transcript_length ~ ., sampleDF, median)
```

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I needed. Just one more follow-up question, if you don't mind. If I wanted to write some custom function, instead of median, for example, how would I do that?

Comment: @ZuhaibAhmed you can create anonymous function (lamba function) on the fly i.e. `aggregate(transcript_length ~ ., sampleDF, FUN = function(x) median(x, na.rm = TRUE))` it can be a custom function as well.  `FUN = f1`

Comment: And I'm assuming that what gets fed into the function is just the values in "transcript_length" that correspond to the value in column 2?

Comment: @ZuhaibAhmed here the `x` is value of the column coming  coming from lhs of `~` i.e. transcript_length'.  The `.` represents all other columns used for grouping.  If you have 100 columns and want to do only grouping with 2 or 3, then specify those columns in the formula with `+`

Comment: Thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, consider using `tapply`:

```
tapply(sampleDF$transcript_length, list(sampleDF$entrezgene_id, sampleDF$ensembl_gene_id), median)
       a    b      c      d    e      f      g    h
1   7059 3972 2709.0     NA   NA     NA     NA   NA
10    NA   NA 5826.5 3573.5 6797     NA     NA   NA
100   NA   NA     NA     NA   NA 2749.5 3335.5 6291
```

The results are displayed in an even more concise way.

Comment: I didn't know about tapply. Thanks for bringing it to my attention. This is definitely useful, but for my purposes right now, I wanted it in the form I mentioned above. And it turns out the aggregate function was exactly what I was looking for.